# Animation with modifiers wont export properly

Tags: animation, modifiers, export

I animated a Mobius strip similarly to this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pF91ExiRkko). So without bones, using keyframes and modifiers. However, when i export my mesh with the animation, it either doesnt have the Bend/Twist modifier i used, or the modifiers are permanently applied. This wont work since i am animating the progress of the modifiers.
Is what i want even possible? Is there a different file type i can use? Or maybe a fix using bones?

If you could provide tutorials for/similar to your fix that would be great i started using blender 4 days ago and am dying inside.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which format do you export your mesh?

Comment: I tried with .fbx, .dae and .gtif. They are the only ones i can easily import in my AR software.